# Box sorting Algorithm proof

Tags: algorithm, proof, proof-of-correctness

i wrote a different proof for the box sorting algorithm in O(n^2) and proved it by induction.

can someone please refute/provide another proof to the solution?

**The Problem-**

You are given a set of n types of rectangular 3-D boxes, where the i^th box has height h(i), width w(i) and depth d(i) (all real numbers). all the **lengths are different**, and **widths are different**.You want to create a stack of boxes which is as tall as possible, but you can only stack a box on top of another box if the dimensions of the 2-D base of the lower box are each strictly larger than those of the 2-D base of the higher box.you can **NOT** rotate a box so that any side functions as its base.

**the known solution-**

- Sort the boxes by ascending base area .
- Create a table t of size n indexed by 1 ≤ i ≤ n. Starting with i = n
  to 1, define t[i] by max { h(i) , max { h(i) + t[j]} for all j>i such that w(j)>w(i) and l(j)>l(i)}
- Return the following value: max {t[1], . . . , t[n]}

**my solution -**

- sort the boxes by ascending width in array W, and by ascending length
  in array L.
- create a nxn matrix, where t[i,j] = tallest possible
  stack built on a L(i) long and W(j) wide base.
- the answer will be in t[n,n] since that is our max possible base
  area.
- for the first row in the matrix (this is the
  tallest stack that can be built on the minimum length base area -
  meaning only the box with the minimum length can be in it)

  define t[1,j]:

  - 0 <--  if W(j) < width of the box with min length
  - height of the box with lowest length <-- if W(j) >= width of the box
- for the first column in the matrix (this is the tallest stack that
  can be built on the minimum width base area - meaning only the box
  with the minimum width can be in it)

  define t[i,1]:

  - 0 <-- if L(i) < length of the box with min width
  - height of the box with lowest width <-- if L(i) >= length of the box with min width
- define t[i,j] = height of the box whose length is L(i) and width is
  W(j) , if such exist +  max { t[i-1,j] , t[i,j-1] }

  - there can only be one box with those attributes since they are all unique.

thank you all!

Comment: this is not the correct stack exchange site. i believe the computer science stack exchange would be better suited.

Comment: @PranavaGande Algorithm questions are fine on S/O.

Comment: as far as i understand, s/o is specifically for coding questions, but i may be wrong

Comment: @PranavaGande: You're wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Though there is an overlap with cs.stackexchange  - see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the "known solution"?

Comment: Is the known solution in O(n^2) time?

Comment: the known solution- https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~nirkhe/cs38notes/recitation_notes/week2rec.pdf on the second page. it is o(n^2) @LiorKogan